# How to Bootstrap from Workstaion to Docker conatiner?

Tags: docker, chef-infra

```
I want to run a role on docker container .How can i achieve it ??

Any syntax of command will be helpful.
```

knife bootstrap -x -P like this

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a container with ssh access, you can use `knife bootstrap`. For example:

```
CONTAINER=$(docker run -d -e ROOT_PASS="mypass" tutum/ubuntu:trusty)
CONTAINERIP=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' ${CONTAINER})
knife bootstrap $CONTAINERIP -x root -P mypass --sudo -r 'role[myrole]'
```

The first line will run a docker container (image [tutum/ubuntu:trusty](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tutum/ubuntu/)) with ssh daemon enabled, and root ssh password set to "mypass". The CONTAINER_ID of this image is returned by `docker run` command and saved to `CONTAINER` variable.

The second command will use this CONTAINER_ID to get the IP address assigned to this conteiner, and save it to `CONTAINERIP` variable.

And the third command bootstraps chef in the container, using the $CONTAINERIP variable to reference its ip, and the ssh credentials of the container. This works supposed you have configured knife correctly.

Note about SSH:
The container you use has to have a daemon ssh running. In docker docs there are references to this (http://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/). Also there are a lot of images in Docker hub with it (as the one in the example tutum/ubuntu:trusty).

Note about exposing SSH port:
If your chef workstation (the one with knife configured) is not the one that runs your container, you can expose ssh port to one's of the host machine and then accessing to your HOST_IP to that port. In example:

```
CONTAINER=$(docker run -d -p 2222:22 -e ROOT_PASS="mypass" tutum/ubuntu:trusty)

knife bootstrap $HOST_IP -p 2222 -x root -P mypass --sudo -r 'role[myrole]'
```

Comment: what do you mean by container ssh access ??

Comment: i have not understand your first two line

Comment: how to make a container ssh access ??

Comment: I have workstation on different machine and docker installed on different machine ...After running two command i got the ip  ..and when i bootstrap to that ip from workstation it is not able to connect to that ip.

Comment: U r great ...very well explained ..Thanks a lot..One more thing how we come to know what port number we have  to expose ,and what is 2222:22 here  represent i mean :22 here

Comment: 22 is default SSH port, and 2222 is the port you choose to map from container's port 22 to your host machine. You can choose other port (to 2222) if you wish. Simply use option `-p` in `knife bootstrap` to indicate the ssh port.

Comment: let we pulled tutum/ubuntu:trusty image on docker host ,then where will be the docker file for the image avaialble ,i m not getting the dockerfile of that (will it get copied on our machine or not)

Comment: Let on doing docker ps ..It list me container id ..and let i want to run some command on running docker (like do porxy setting ).How should i do that on running container and after that should i need to do commit it .

Comment: You can run using `docker exec` command. PD: If you prefer chat in IRC or making new questions if needed it is better suited that doing in comments.